# Failed to load trusted CA certificates from <inline>

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

Unable to set up mTLS on the gateway. If I set gateway `mode: MUTUAL` then `istio-ingressgateway` outputs
`Failed to load trusted CA certificates from <inline>`. I am using [Cloudflare origin pull CA cert](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/authenticated-origin-pull/set-up#certificate-value). With the `mode: SIMPLE` secret works as expected.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true

secretGenerator:
  - name: mysite.com-cer
    namespace: istio-system
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    files:
      - tls.key=certs/mysite.com.key
      - tls.crt=certs/mysite.com.cer
      - ca.crt=certs/cloudflare-ca.crt
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gw

spec:
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - 'mysite.com'
        - '*.mysite.com'

      port:
        number: 1443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS

      tls:
        mode: MUTUAL
        credentialName: mysite.com-cer
```

Istio 1.12.1

Comment: Did you check the contents of  the ca.crt value in your secret? To see if it indeed contains the correct CA?

Comment: OMG! So much pain, so much heartache for such reason! Line endings were the problem. Please write your answer I will accept.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, could you write an answer so it will be visible for the community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the contents of the ca.crt value in the generated secret and make sure it is a valid certificate.

`Failed to load trusted CA certificates from <inline>` indicates the the certificate is  empty or invalid.